# What is the maximum number of email addresses that can be in a cfmail

Tags: email, coldfusion, cfmail

Is there a maximum number of email addresses that can be included in a cfmail message? Is this number the maximum in each of the to, cc, and bcc or a combined maximum?

Comment: You probably need to check the appropriate RFC for SMTP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a maximum, other than the maximum length of a string, which I couldn't find in a quick search.  I suggest using the BCC attribute to send your messages to.  Also, if you have a lot of email addresses, you may want to use a list service.  It makes management easier, the most mail servers will handle delivery better.

-Jay

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if coldfusion has a limit per se, but it would be advisable to loop through your lists and send individual emails.  This helps keep the email addresses "private", and not exposed to other members.

Comment: We will be putting all the addresses in the BCC. This way, only one email is sent instead of hundreds (or thousands).

Comment: You probably don't want to do that. One bad address or some other error may prevent the message from being sent to anyone. You might also run afoul of some spam filters if you have to many recipients in one field. Better to send individual messages, I think, and space them out over time.

Comment: yeah, you could do this with CF threads or even a loop that causes the template to "hang"